# Build custom error messages in model files (example: using the 'pluralize' method)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to use the `pluralize` method in a my model file in order to properly build custom error messages.

For example, I would like to do something like the following:

```
NAME_MIN_LENGHT = 2 # the value is '2' but I plan to change that (maybe dynamically... if it is possible) in future development

validates :name,
  :length     => {
    :minimum        => NAME_MIN_LENGHT,
    :too_short      => "is too short (minimum is #{pluralize(NAME_MIN_LENGHT, 'character')})",
  },
```

**How can I do that? Is it advisable? Why?**

Comment: Don't know if this works, but have you tried using a lambda? I think you are over engineering it, though. The effort you put in this outweighs the effort of changing the `:minimum` and the error message - should they ever change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to agree with Wukerplank that this looks a bit overengineered, but it's still an interesting question.  According to [this](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1799) post you can use helpers in controller methods:

Put this in the class ApplicationController:

```
 def help
    Helper.instance
  end

  class Helper
    include Singleton
    include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
  end
```

Then you can just use it like so:

```
def check_for_max_donkeys
    if Donkey.find_fit_donkeys.size == APP_SETTINGS['max_fit_donkeys']
      flash_error "The maximum of #{help.pluralize(APP_SETTINGS['max_fit_donkeys'], 'donkey')} has been reached."
      redirect_to_index
    end
  end
```

I think something similar should work inside your validation method, but I've not tried it out - do leave a note if it works please :-)